# CAGradientLayer Locations in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, cagradientlayer

I know that the swift array bridges to NSarray.

Swift array can only contain one type.

I want to set the locations for CAGradientLayer in swift.

I need to nil terminate the array.

Are the only options:
A.) create an NSArray object with floats and nil at the end?
B.) create a swift array that contains an array of anyObjects so I can specify nil?

I am a little confused about how to approach the problem.

Swift nil != Objective C nil

so does this mean I cannot nil terminate the array the same way as objective c?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite simple:

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
let locations = [ 0.0, 1.0 ]
layer.locations = locations
```

Note that Objective-C arrays are *not* nil-terminated.
You are perhaps confused by the syntax

```
NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: loc1, loc2, nil];
```

This creates an array with *two* objects. `nil` is only a sentinel for the variable argument list and not stored in the array. In fact Objective-C array cannot store `nil` at all. In "modern" Objective-C, this would be written as

```
NSArray *locations = @[loc1, loc2];
```

and that translates to the above Swift code.

Comment: thanks I got confused about how locations worked
The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing. If nil, the stops are spread uniformly across the range. Defaults to nil.

I thought this meant that when it's reading from the array it waits till it sees the nil it stops spreading the color.